# Loading external URL inside Ionic v2 controller

Tags: iframe, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to render a remote web page inside my Ionic2 controller without using the inAppBrowser.

Researching online I found two methods:

### FIRST METHOD

**panorama.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
      <ion-title>Panorama</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
  <div>
      <div [innerHTML]="myVal"></div>

  </div>

</ion-content>
```

**panorama.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,NavParams,Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from 'ionic-native';
import {SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-panorama',
  templateUrl: 'panorama.html'
})

export class PanoramaPage {

  myVal: any;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private alertCtrl: AlertController,public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,public http: Http) {

        this.myVal = this.http.get('http://www.facebook.com').map(response => response.text()).subscribe(html => this.myVal = html);

      }
}
```

it doesn't work...shows just `[object][object]`

### SECOND METHOD

using an iframe in the template:

```
<iframe ng-src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe>
```

and in the **config.xml**

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

but the iframe is always blank.

Getting crazy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running into CORS errors then you will need to get around that one way or another, one way is to use a CORS proxy such as `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` 
Below is my working code for loading in the HTML into an ionic page

```
let proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
this.myVal = this.http
  .get(proxyurl + 'https://www.google.com')
  .map(response => response.text())
  .subscribe(
    function (data) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("ion-content")[0].innerHTML = data;
    }
);
```